# How to create sqlite prepared statement in OrmLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, ormlite

Is it possible to create a sqlite prepared statement in OrmLite? 
If so, how to bind the query values which may change across different queries.

Comment: Did you check the documentation?
http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_3.html#Statement-Builder

Comment: Yes, which of the quoted elements are prepared stataments?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a sqlite prepared statement in OrmLite?

You need to RTFM since ORMLite's [online documentation](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite.html) is pretty extensive.  If you look in the index for ["prepared statement"](http://ormlite.com/docs/prepared-statement) you find out about the `QueryBuilder` which @Egor pointed out.

> how to bind the query values which may change across different queries.

A little further in that section you learn about [select arguments](http://ormlite.com/docs/select-arg) which is how you bind query values that change across queries.  This is in the index under "arguments to queries".

To quote from the docs here's how you prepare a custom query:

```
QueryBuilder<Account, String> queryBuilder = dao.queryBuilder();
Where<Account, String> where = queryBuilder.where();
SelectArg selectArg = new SelectArg();
// define our query as 'name = ?'
where.eq("name", selectArg);
// prepare it so it is ready for later query or iterator calls
PreparedQuery<Account> preparedQuery = queryBuilder.prepare();
```

When you are ready to run the query you set the select argument and issue the query:

```
selectArg.setValue("foo");
List<Account> accounts = dao.query(preparedQuery);
```

Later, you can set the select argument to *another* value and re-run the query:

```
selectArg.setValue("bar");
accounts = accountDao.query(preparedQuery);
```

Comment: You made my day. I was supposing QueryBuilder is for that but didn't know SelectArg is for replacing query values. Thanks!